# How to remove selector from Html.TextBoxFor?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, .net, razor

I have a little problem with Html.TextBoxFor. All i need is to remove the selector.

[image]

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartFund.Funds, new { id = "startFundsTextBox", @class = "k-textbox", @style = "width:20%; display:inline-block", @type = "number", @min = "0" })
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `css` you can remove spinners from input type number.

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='number' />
```

Comment: Thats it! Thank u very much :)

Comment: Glad to help .Up vote and accept answer. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `@type="number"` attribute (and therefore also `@min`  as it is now irrelevant):

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.StartFund.Funds, new { id = "startFundsTextBox", @class = "k-textbox", @style = "width:20%; display:inline-block" })
```

This makes it a normal textbox, rather than a numeric input.

Comment: Thx for u answer but I want to stay with @type="number" and ONLY remove the selector.